# Unable to completely remove NiFi state in Mac (local setup)

Tags: apache-nifi

I installed the local version of NiFi and was creating a flow with InvokeHTTP processor. This resulted in an error and I got

{
      "status": 404,
      "message": "Not Found"
   }

I then tried to stop and restart the processors but I kept getting this error. Now even I go to http://localhost:8080/nifi I get the same message
{
  "status": 404,
  "message": "Not Found"
}

I did a brew uninstall nifi followed by brew install nifi, but I still keep getting the 404-Not found when trying to open NiFi UI.

How can I resolve this. Please help.

Comment: what link you are using to access nifi?

Comment: check nifi bootstrap and nifi app logs to see if there is any error

Comment: Please stop signing your posts, signatures and taglines are considered noise here.